# What am I doing wrong in Orientrom?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, orientdb

I am using module orientorm which i downloaded from github (https://github.com/mav-im/orientorm) 
and I also add come lines of code in ./lib/index.js after line No. 23

```
this.Scehma = require('./dbSchema');
this.Model = require('./model');
this.Query = require('./query');
```

So that I can use other modules. I search on google for help. But I can not find any content about ur module.

Here is my code

```
orientorm = require('orientorm'),
orntSchema = orientorm.Scehma; 

var UserScehma = new orntSchema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  user: {
    type: orntSchema.Types.Link,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

orientorm.Model('UserScehma', UserScehma);
```

But I got this error...

```
.\lib\model\
    this.$__.strictMode = schema.builtOpts && schema.builtOpts.strict;
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'builtOpts' of undefined
    at Orientorm.Doc (D:\orientrom_app_prec_1\node_modules\orientorm\lib\model\Document.js:35:33)
    at Orientorm.Model (D:\orientrom_app_prec_1\node_modules\orientorm\lib\model\index.js:13:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\orientrom_app_prec_1\app.js:27:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: `Scehma` should be `Schema`.

Comment: Thanks Ocaso Protal ! But still same error.